# OpenCV: Why projectPoints() is giving me weird results?

Tags: opencv, 3d, projection, camera-calibration

Why is my code snippet giving me weird results for projected points?

```
//Generate the one 3D Point which i want to project onto 2D plane
vector<Point3d> points_3d;
points_3d.push_back(Point3d(10, 10, 100));
Mat points3d = Mat(points_3d);

//Generate the identity matrix and zero vector for rotation matrix and translation vector
Mat rvec = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1));
Mat tvec = (Mat_<double>(3, 1) << (0, 0, 0));

//Generate a camera intrinsic matrix
Mat K = (Mat_<double>(3,3) 
<< (1000, 0, 50,
    0, 1000, 50,
    0, 0, 1));

//Project the 3D Point onto 2D plane
Mat points_2d;

projectPoints(points_3d, rvec, tvec, K, Mat(), points_2d);

//Output
cout << points_2d;
```

I get as projected 2D Point
points_2d = (-1.708699427820658e+024, -9.673395654445999e-026)

If i calculate it on a paper on my own, i'm expecting a point points_2d = (150, 150) with that formula: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `cv::Rodrigues(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, OutputArray jacobian=noArray())`. OpenCv uses rotation vector inside calculation instead of rotation matrix. Rodrigues transformation allows you to convert rotation vector to matrix and matrix to vector. Below i attached part of your code with one line added.

```
//Generate the identity matrix and zero vector for rotation matrix and translation vector
Mat rvec,rMat = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1));
Rodrigues(rMat,rvec); //here
Mat tvec = (Mat_<double>(3, 1) << (0, 0, 0));
```

And it should work properly. It also will be better to define distortion coefficents as

```
 Mat dist = Mat::zeros(8,1,CV_32f);
```

EDIT:

One more remark, you have little syntax error in matrix initialization:

```
cv::Mat rvec,rMat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << /* ( */1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1); //you had error here
cv::Rodrigues(rMat, rvec);
cv::Mat tvec = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 1) <</* ( */ 0, 0, 0); //and here
```

It works on my computer after changes.

Comment: FYI, you can use back ticks (\`) around statements to produce in-line code. I.e. \`this\` produces `this`.

Comment: It is still giving some weird result... `points_2d = [-2.189252230068162, 2.108690908231197e-026]`

Comment: Thanks Kamil.. That little syntax error in matrix initialization was the problem!

Comment: I also changed initialization of your K matrix:  `cv::Mat K2 = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1000, 0, 50, 0, 1000, 50, 0, 0, 1);` and then I got points_2d = [150, 150] as you wished